# SQL Queries from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I am taking a beginner's course in SQL, and have been playing around with some queries. One thing I don't really understand is how to "properly" query multiple tables, that is; compare values from two or more tables.

For instance, 
I have a table called **Student**, holding the username, name, date of birth, and major (just the code. For instance, CS would stand for "Computer Science") of a particular person. I chose to make the username a primary key.

I also have another table called **Major** holding the major code (such as CS) as a primary key, and the entire major name. For instance, "CS" = "Computer Science", NS = "Neuroscience", etc.

Now, suppose I want to find the name of a major, given a student's username. Following is the imagined pseudocode for this query:

1) In the **Student** table: Provided the username, check what the major of that particular person is.

```
select majorcode from Student where username='aUserName';
```

Doing so correctly gives me the major code.

2) In the **Major** table: Find the title of the major provided the code.

```
select majorTitle from Major where majorcode='theMajorCode';
```

Combinded, I write:

```
select majorTitle from Major where majorcode=(select majorcode from Student where username='aUserName');
```

However, now suppose I want **BOTH** the **title of the major** (from the Major table) as well as the **name of the student** (from the Student table).

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a *join*. Something like this - note that any rows in Student that have a majorcode not in Major, or vice-versa, will not be included. If that's not what you want, look into *outer joins*.

```
SELECT majorTitle, username
FROM Student s
JOIN Major m ON s.majorcode = m.majorcode
```

You can of course add a WHERE clause to that query. Reference tables using the aliases ("s" for Student, "m" for Major) to avoid ambiguity.